# How to mock a BulkWriteException in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, python-unittest

I need to get the information contained in the exception. This is the code I use.

```
try:
    result = yield user_collection.insert_many(content, ordered=False)
except BulkWriteError as e:
    print (e)
```

And in my test when I get into the except with this line,

```
self.insert_mock.side_effect = [BulkWriteError('')]
```

it returns me

> batch op errors occurred

instead of a MagicMock or a Mock.

How can I mock the `BulkWriteError` and give it a default `return_value` and see it when I use `print(e)`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should allow you to test your print was called correctly.

```
import builtins # mockout print

class BulkWriteErrorStub(BulkWriteError):
  ''' Stub out the exception so you can bypass the constructor. '''

  def __str__:
    return 'fake_error'

@mock.patch.object('builtins', 'print')
def testRaisesBulkWrite(self, mock_print):
  ...
  self.insert_mock.side_effect = [BuilkWriteErrorStub]
  with self.assertRaises(...):
    mock_print.assert_called_once_with('fake_error')
```

I haven't tested this so feel free to edit it if I made a mistake.

Comment: It returned that `builtins` doesn't have the `print` method, but if I remove that decorator, It should print the 'fake_error' anyway, and didn't happened.

Comment: Prints will usually not appear inside of a unit test, or they haven't for me. Try importing `__builtins__` instead. That is the way I do it with Python2.